# Import URL as jpg and size largest column width and row height of image

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on downloading about 8k jpg files from the net. The URL for the files is in column B and I want to output the actual image in column C. I have some code I've mangled together to do the download but the images are coming in small. I want them to come in the original size. So, I'd like to determine what the biggest jpg file is and make the row height and column width match it. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Test2()
Dim Pic As Picture
Dim SrcRange As Range
Dim LastRowA As Long

    LastRowA = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

    Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRowA, 1))

    SrcRange.Rows().RowHeight = ActiveSheet.Columns(3).Width * 2

    For Each cell In SrcRange.Cells
        With cell
            Set Pic = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(.Value)
            With .Offset(, 1)
                Pic.Top = .Top
                Pic.Left = .Left
                Pic.Height = .Height
                Pic.Width = .Width
                Pic.Border.Color = vbRed
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

As always, any help will be greatly appreciated. It has been about 5 years since I've done any excel vba coding. I'm a little rusty. I'm running excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Set the picture aspect ratio to false.

```
Pic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
```

In your code..

```
For Each cell In SrcRange.Cells
    With cell
        Set Pic = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(.Value)
        Pic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse '<~~ set LockAspetRatio to false
        With .Offset(, 1)
            Pic.Top = .Top
            Pic.Left = .Left
            Pic.Height = .Height
            Pic.Width = .Width
            Pic.Border.Color = vbRed
        End With
    End With
Next
```

End Sub

### In the above method, the picture is not saved as an Excel file, only a link is set. To save a picture to an Excel file, do the following:

```
Sub Test2()
Dim Pic As Picture
Dim SrcRange As Range
Dim LastRowA As Long
Dim l As Single, t As Single, w As Single, h As Single
Dim cell As Range

    LastRowA = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

    Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRowA, 1))

    SrcRange.Rows().RowHeight = ActiveSheet.Columns(3).Width * 2

    For Each cell In SrcRange.Cells
        With cell
            t = .Top
            l = .Left
            w = .Width
            h = .Height
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(.Value, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, l, t, w, h)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```